# Issue about regular expressions

Tags: javascript, replace

## Create a list from a regular expresion

I was trying creating a list from a regular expression, and I have this (http://regexr.com/3g1hn):

```
+ Hola
+ Adios
+ wii
```

And I want to get this by using a regular expression:

```
<ul>
  <li>Hola</li>
  <li>Adios</li>
  <li>wii</li>
<ul>
```

I want to make this but with javascript or else with other language.

How can i get this?

Comment: Where is your code? What doesn't work?

Comment: It seems to work just fine, based on the regexr link. Just add it between "<ul>" and "</ul>".

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it

```
// using template strings
const string = `+ Hola
+ Adios
+ wii`;

const replaced = string.replace(/\+\s(\w+)(\n\r)?/g, '<li>$1</li>');
const fullList = '<ul>' + replaced + '</ul>';
```

Comment: @RaulContreras then replace the 'string' variable with whatever your string is

Comment: Ok. What else can the string contain? Please edit your question with examples

Comment: I test moreless what you have purposed back, but didn`t worked me. What I want is for example, that in a markdown document, the lists wrap, the li's tags in <ul> tags, but only the li's tags and not the <ul>

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your question